# Complex number question help

Tags: calculus

How would I find the solutions in polar form to $$z^3=-8$$  Can you provide a step by step solution?

Comment: You go first.  What was your first step?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$-8=8e^{(2k+1)\pi i}$$

for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus,

$$z=2e^{\frac{2k+1}3\pi i}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Without the polar form**:

Notice that

$$z^3+8=(z+2)(z^2-2z+4).$$

Then the roots are $-2$ and $1\pm i\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation  $Z^n=z_0$ we have n roots which are:

> $Z_k = n\sqrt{r} (\cos \frac{\theta +2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\theta +2k\pi}{n})$ where r is modulus of $z_0$.

So, In your equation, you will get three values of $Z$ which will be $-2$ and $1\pm i\sqrt3$.